# Tensorflow: Simple 3D Convnet not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I am trying to create a **simple 3D U-net for image segmentation**, just to learn how to use the layers. Therefore I do a 3D convolution with stride 2 and then a transpose deconvolution to get back the same image size. I am also overfitting to a small set (test set) just to see if my network is learning.

I created the same net in Keras and it works just fine. Now I want to create in tensorflow but I been having trouble with it.

The **cost changes slightly** but no matter what I do (reduce learning rate, add more epochs, add more layers, change batch size...) the output is always the same. I believe the net is not updating the weights. I am sure I am doing something wrong but I can find what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciate it.

Here is **my code**:

```
def forward_propagation(X):

    if ( mode == 'train'): print(" --------- Net --------- ")

    # Convolutional Layer 1
    with tf.variable_scope('CONV1'):
        Z1 = tf.layers.conv3d(X, filters = 16, kernel =[3,3,3], strides = [ 2, 2, 2], padding='SAME', name = 'S2/conv3d')
        A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1, name = 'S2/ReLU')
        if ( mode == 'train'): print("Convolutional Layer 1 S2 " + str(A1.get_shape()))

    # DEConvolutional Layer 1
    with tf.variable_scope('DeCONV1'):
        output_deconv1 = tf.stack([X.get_shape()[0] , X.get_shape()[1], X.get_shape()[2], X.get_shape()[3], 1])
        dZ1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(A1,  filters = 1, kernel =[3,3,3], strides = [2, 2, 2], padding='SAME', name = 'S2/conv3d_transpose')
        dA1 = tf.nn.relu(dZ1, name = 'S2/ReLU')

        if ( mode == 'train'): print("Deconvolutional Layer 1 S1 " + str(dA1.get_shape()))

    return dA1


def compute_cost(output, target, method = 'dice_hard_coe'):

    with tf.variable_scope('COST'):       

        if (method == 'sigmoid_cross_entropy') :
            # Make them vectors
            output = tf.reshape( output, [-1, output.get_shape().as_list()[0]] )
            target = tf.reshape( target, [-1, target.get_shape().as_list()[0]] )
            loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, labels = target)
            cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    return cost
```

and the main function for **the model**:

```
def model(X_h5, Y_h5, learning_rate = 0.009,
          num_epochs = 100, minibatch_size = 64, print_cost = True):


    ops.reset_default_graph()                         # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
    #tf.set_random_seed(1)                             # to keep results consistent (tensorflow seed)
    #seed = 3                                          # to keep results consistent (numpy seed)
    (m, n_D, n_H, n_W, num_channels) = X_h5["test_data"].shape   #TTT          
    num_labels = Y_h5["test_mask"].shape[4] #TTT
    img_size = Y_h5["test_mask"].shape[1]  #TTT
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost
    accuracies = []                                   # To keep track of the accuracy



    # Create Placeholders of the correct shape
    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H, n_W, n_D, minibatch_size)

    # Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
    nn_output = forward_propagation(X)
    prediction = tf.nn.sigmoid(nn_output)

    # Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
    cost_method = 'sigmoid_cross_entropy' 
    cost = compute_cost(nn_output, Y, cost_method)

    # Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer that minimizes the cost.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Initialize all the variables globally
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


    # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        print('------ Training ------')

        # Run the initialization
        tf.local_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
        sess.run(init)

        # Do the training loop
        for i in range(num_epochs*m):
            # ----- TRAIN -------
            current_epoch = i//m            

            patient_start = i-(current_epoch * m)
            patient_end = patient_start + minibatch_size

            current_X_train = np.zeros((minibatch_size, n_D,  n_H, n_W,num_channels))
            current_X_train[:,:,:,:,:] = np.array(X_h5["test_data"][patient_start:patient_end,:,:,:,:]) #TTT
            current_X_train = np.nan_to_num(current_X_train) # make nan zero

            current_Y_train = np.zeros((minibatch_size, n_D, n_H, n_W, num_labels))
            current_Y_train[:,:,:,:,:] = np.array(Y_h5["test_mask"][patient_start:patient_end,:,:,:,:]) #TTT
            current_Y_train = np.nan_to_num(current_Y_train) # make nan zero

            feed_dict = {X: current_X_train, Y: current_Y_train}
            _ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict=feed_dict)

            # ----- TEST -------
            # Print the cost every 1/5 epoch
            if ((i % (num_epochs*m/5) )== 0):              

                # Calculate the predictions
                test_predictions = np.zeros(Y_h5["test_mask"].shape)

                for j in range(0, X_h5["test_data"].shape[0], minibatch_size):

                    patient_start = j
                    patient_end = patient_start + minibatch_size

                    current_X_test = np.zeros((minibatch_size, n_D,  n_H, n_W, num_channels))
                    current_X_test[:,:,:,:,:] = np.array(X_h5["test_data"][patient_start:patient_end,:,:,:,:])
                    current_X_test = np.nan_to_num(current_X_test) # make nan zero

                    current_Y_test = np.zeros((minibatch_size, n_D, n_H, n_W, num_labels))
                    current_Y_test[:,:,:,:,:] = np.array(Y_h5["test_mask"][patient_start:patient_end,:,:,:,:]) 
                    current_Y_test = np.nan_to_num(current_Y_test) # make nan zero

                    feed_dict = {X: current_X_test, Y: current_Y_test}
                    _, current_prediction = sess.run([cost, prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    test_predictions[j:j + minibatch_size,:,:,:,:] = current_prediction

                costs.append(temp_cost)
                print ("[" + str(current_epoch) + "|" + str(num_epochs) + "] " + "Cost : " + str(costs[-1]))
                display_progress(X_h5["test_data"], Y_h5["test_mask"], test_predictions, 5, n_H, n_W)

        # plot the cost
        plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
        plt.ylabel('cost')
        plt.xlabel('epochs')
        plt.show()

        return
```

I call the model with:

```
model(hdf5_data_file, hdf5_mask_file, num_epochs = 500, minibatch_size = 1, learning_rate = 1e-3)
```

These are the results that I am currently getting:
[image]
[image]

**Edit**:
I have tried reducing the learning rate and it doesn't help. I also tried using tensorboard debug and the weights are not being updated:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening.
I Created the same simple model in keras and it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in tensorflow.

Comment: My guess would be that the learning step size is too large such that you take one step and bam... the ReLus all start saturating. Two ways to confirm would be to use leaky Relus, or to drastically reduce the learning rate. In any event, leaky ReLus may be a good idea

Comment: Hi @bremen_matt, I have reduce the learning rate without any success. I also used tensordoard debug and notice that the weights are not being updated. Any ideas?

Comment: I would try changing those relus to leaky relus. Learning will stop if you get pushed over to the side of the relus where everything is 0.

Comment: What happens if you remove the nan_to_num() calls?  Do you get a ton of NaNs?  If so, try to figure out why, because if you do it looks like something is wrong with the calculations and your entire network will output 0 and the ReLUs won't be able to learn anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for help, as I am answering this question half a year later your posted date. :)  I've listed my observations and also some suggestions for you to try below.  It my primary observation is right... then you probably just need a coffee break / a night of good sleep.

primary observation:

- `tf.reshape( output, [-1, output.get_shape().as_list()[0]] )` seems wrong. If you prefer to flatten the vector, it should be something like `tf.reshape(output,[-1,np.prod(image_shape_list)])`.

other observations:

- With such a shallow network, I doubt the network have enough spatial resolution to differentiate tumor voxels from non-tumor voxels.  Can you show the keras implementation and the performance compared to a pure tf implementation? I would probably go with 2+ layers, let's .
  say with 3 layers, with a stride of 2 per layer, and an input image width of 256, you will end with a width of 32 at your deepest encoder layer. (If you have a limited GPU memory, downsample the input image.)
- if changing the loss computation does not work, as @bremen_matt mentioned, reduce LR to say maybe 1e-5.
- after the basic architecture tweaks and you "feel" that the network is sort of learning and not stuck, try augmenting the training data, add dropout, batch norm during training, and then maybe fancy up your loss by adding a discriminator.

Comment: As I mentioned this is only to get the code working. I am not expecting it to solve the problem, although keras does a decent job with only these two layers. Also, as stated in the edit, I have tried to lower the LR with no luck. The entire purpose of this net is just to get the same results I am getting in keras but using tensorflow.